# Can VSFTPD read home dir from LDAP backend?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

Is it some how possible to make `VSFTPD` **read the home of each user from LDAP backend?** The users authenticates against `LDAP`  backend over `PAM`. I do NOT want to create any user_config files, I just want to make `VSFTPD` to read it from user's `LDAP` directory. Is it some how possible?

I want to use that home dir to `chroot` the users in it.

Answer (score 1):

OK I did it using the following two options in `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
```

> passwd_chroot_enable
>   If enabled, along with chroot_local_user , then a chroot() jail location may be specified on a per-user basis. Each user's jail is derived from their home directory string in /etc/passwd. The occurrence of /./ in the home directory string denotes that the jail is at that particular location in the path.